# Format Timezone for Carbon Date

Tags: php, laravel, timezone, laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm trying to set the timezone for a date in a `Carbon` object. It works fine locally but on my production box it keeps giving me `Bad timezone` error.

I've tried:

```
$date->setTimezone('7');
$date->setTimezone('+7');
$date->setTimezone('7:00');
$date->setTimezone('+7:00');
$date->setTimezone('UTC 7');
$date->setTimezone('UTC +7');
$date->setTimezone('UTC 7:00');
$date->setTimezone('UTC +7:00');
```

No idea why it's complaining on my production box. Can't find documentation either on what is the "proper" format to enter here. Can someone please help.

FYI: local is windows, and prod is Ubuntu box.

Comment: is it the same as the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447379/carbonnow-with-time-offset-result-in-different-behaviors)?

Comment: `$d = Carbon::now()->setTimezone(request_timezone());` This line: 1 it won't change timestamp (aka `$d->getTimestamp();` is the same as `$d2 = Carbon::now(); $d2->getTimestamp();`) 2 it works as it sets the timezone so that it can return the correct startOfDay() timestamp in that timezone aka *YOUR_TZ 00:00's timestamp*. (when not setting timezone and calls startOfDay(), it returns *UTC 00:00's timestamp*)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can change the timezone with this:

```
$timestamp = '2014-02-06 16:34:00';
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp, 'Europe/Stockholm');
$date->setTimezone('UTC');
```

this format working fine to my Local(Ubuntu) and prod(Redhat) project.

Comment: I was stuck because I tried to set timezone with createFromTimestamp, even if it accepts second param. Apparently, Timestamp is always in UTC...

Comment: @mladen-janjetović can you show me your code, how you trying?

Comment: if you want to change application wise format, you should setup config/app.timezone component as per your requirement.

Comment: something like this if i remember well `$date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($timestamp, 'EST');` It is not returning right time when call ->timezone('UTC') on this. app.timezone is set to UTC.
With this createFromFormat it works well.

Comment: Would Carbon take Daylight savings time into account?

Answer (score 19):

I think you should refer to the [official php timezone list](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php). In your case you can use

```
$date->setTimezone('Asia/Phnom_Penh');
```

for UTC+7:00.

Answer (score 14):

For people wondering, you can chain the timezone like so:

```
Carbon::now()->timezone('Europe/Stockholm')
```