# Get delay hours and extra hours using Carbon library in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm working on a attendance report and need to display the delay and overtime hours times using carbon  , I'm calculation the difference between time In and TimeOut, then subtract 1 hour (lunch hour) , i have problem subtracting 1 hour.

Second , once the above is ready I need to calculate the real employee arrival and departure times and get the difference to get hours worked.

```
      $timeIn = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $hra_entrada_m); //08:00 am
      $timeOut = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $hra_salida_t);  //17:30 pm

      $time1 =  $timeIn->diff($timeOut);          <- 9:30
      $time1 =  $time1->subtract(60, 'minutes');     <- problem   
      return  $time1->format('%H:%i');            ->should display 8:30


      $employeeTimeIn = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $emp_time_in); //08:15 am
      $employeeTimeOut = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $emp_time_out); //17:40 pm
      $time2 =  $employeeTimeIn->diff($employeeTimeOut);
```

now to get diference between time1 and time2 i want to convert them in milliseconds,

```
      $hours_worked = ($time1->milliseconds() - $time2->milliseconds() )
```

Image of sum error:
[adding two times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ecka.png)

Comment: Is `$time` instead of `$time1` a typo in this line `$time->subtract(60, 'minutes');`?

Comment: yes, it's $time1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are confusing the return object of `diff`. Carbon's `diff` does not return a Carbon object, but a DateInterval object. This object does not have `sub` function. So, one way to do this is to substract the time from Carbon first and then calculate diff. It would be something like this:

```
$timeIn = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', '08:00'); //08:00 am
$timeOut = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', '17:30');  //17:30 pm

$time1 = $timeIn->diff($timeOut->subMinutes(60)); // <-8:30
```

The second issue is that DateInterval class does not have a milliseconds() class. So you would have to create your own. Here http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/dateinterval.format.php you can find the calculation. So, the function would be:

```
function dateIntervalToMilli($interval)
{
    $days = $interval->format('%a');
    $seconds = 0;
    if($days){
        $seconds += 24 * 60 * 60 * $days;
    }
    $hours = $interval->format('%H');
    if($hours){
        $seconds += 60 * 60 * $hours;
    }
    $minutes = $interval->format('%i');
    if($minutes){
        $seconds += 60 * $minutes;
    }
    $seconds += $interval->format('%s');
    $milliseconds = $seconds * 1000;
    return $milliseconds;
}
```

And now, using this function you can do something like this:

```
$employeeTimeIn = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', '08:15'); //08:15 am
$employeeTimeOut = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', '17:40'); //17:40 pm
$time2 =  $employeeTimeIn->diff($employeeTimeOut);  

$t1Milli = dateIntervalToMilli($time1);
$t2Milli = dateIntervalToMilli($time2);

$diffMilli = $t1Milli - $t2Milli;
```

And to convert `$diffMilli` to H:i you can use:

```
$date = date("H:i", $diffMilli/1000);
```

This is the main idea.

Comment: Hello Laerte, i implemented your solution, in this case i added to times

Comment: result in the image attached above , the correct result should be 07:10

Comment: What code did you use to convert $diffMilli to hours and minutes? I used the same code here and the result is 7:10 if I sum and don't use `subMinutes(60)`.

Comment: I added a code at the end to convert milli to date.

Comment: thanks laerte, i had missed the division,   how do i put the timezone ("america/Santiago") , i get 04:10 , should be 07:10

Comment: You have to set it in Carbon. Check if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600330/format-timezone-for-carbon-date